# How much water should be on my pool cover?

Tags: pool, winterizing, cover

I just covered my above ground pool, following the instructions supplied with the cover.

> - Inflate pillow to about 50%.
> - Install pillow in middle of pool using supplied leads.
> - Drape cover over the pool.
> - Thread cable through eyelets in cover.
> - Insert both ends of cable into turnbuckle, and tighten slightly.
> - Pull cover into position as turnbuckle is tightened (do not over tighten).
> - Put water on top of the cover.

I had a good, even distribution of water on the cover this morning. Then the wind kicked up a bit, and now all the water is on one side of the cover. Should I add more water on top of the cover? How much water is too much?

Comment: What happens when it rains? You need a pool cover for your pool cover?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick You get more water on the cover for a bit, until it evaporates?  I've heard of people pumping water off the cover in the middle of the winter, because there was "too much" on the cover. I'm a first time pool owner, so I have no idea what to expect.